# Symfony & Doctrine: Log changes in a table with an Event Listener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In a Symfony 3 project I have an entity that I want to audit the changes in some of the properties, so I though I could create an Event Listener to store them.

More or less the entity is as follows:

- ReceivedEmail: agent and caseDetail are the properties I want to audit
- ReceivedEmailChange: previousAgent, currentAgent and previousCaseDetail and currentCaseDetail

And the EventListener looks as follows

```
    /**
     * @param OnFlushEventArgs $args
     */
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        /** @var ReceivedEmail $entity */
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
        $unitOfWork = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork();

        $updates = $unitOfWork->getScheduledEntityUpdates();

        foreach ($updates as $entity) {

            if ($entity instanceof ReceivedEmail) {

                $changes = $unitOfWork->getEntityChangeSet($entity);

                $this->receivedEmailChanges[] = $this->receivedEmailChangeManager
                    ->getReceivedEmailChanges($entity, $changes);
            }
        }
    }

public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();

        $i = 0;
        foreach($this->receivedEmailChanges as $receivedEmailChange) {
            $em->persist($receivedEmailChange);
            unset($this->receivedEmailChanges[$i]);
            $i++;
        }

        if ($i > 0) {
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
```

The problem is calling $entityManager->flush() on the postFlush method ends up in an infinte loop and on this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached,
> aborting! in
> /var/www/sellbytel/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php
> on line 187

So my question is: how can I save the changes in the database from the EventListener if it is even possible? If not, is there a workaround to create this log?

Comment: IMHO you can not use the `onFlush` event to define an array of changes you need to process and than after processing these changes in `postFlush` starting the whole process again. Instead of relying on the unitOfWork you can try to replace the onFlush listener by manually saving old and new values using the `preUpdate` and `postUpdate` events instead.

Comment: [Loggable behaviour for Doctrine2](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md) might be of use to you.

Answer (score 3):

If username or password field of `User` changes, log is written to `UserAudit` table so same logic as database triggers. You can adjust it to your needs.

Ref: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ew0r/logging-field-changes-with-a-trigger-like-event-listener-for-auditing-purposes

**services.yml**

```
services:
    application_backend.event_listener.user_entity_audit:
        class: Application\BackendBundle\EventListener\UserEntityAuditListener
        arguments: [ @security.context ]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postFlush }
```

**Listener**

```
namespace Application\BackendBundle\EventListener;

use Application\BackendBundle\Entity\User;
use Application\BackendBundle\Entity\UserAudit;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

class UserEntityAuditListener
{
    private $securityContext;
    private $fields = ['username', 'password'];
    private $audit = [];

    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContextInterface)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContextInterface;
    }

    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args) // OR LifecycleEventArgs
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof User) {
            foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
                if ($args->getOldValue($field) != $args->getNewValue($field)) {
                    $audit = new UserAudit();
                    $audit->setField($field);
                    $audit->setOld($args->getOldValue($field));
                    $audit->setNew($args->getNewValue($field));
                    $audit->setUser($this->securityContext->getToken()->getUsername());

                    $this->audit[] = $audit;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        if (! empty($this->audit)) {
            $em = $args->getEntityManager();

            foreach ($this->audit as $audit) {
                $em->persist($audit);
            }

            $this->audit = [];
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```